# How can I get GDB to print the contents of only a specific member of a struct?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have address that I know of which struct it is.

So by doing  `p *(struct demo.head *) 0x7fff1631a0` in GDB it prints

```
$55 = {
  static demo_tent= 190 '\276',
  header = {
    demo1=34324
    demo2=3242342
  },
  paysacle= 453535345345""
}
```

What I want is only to print header portion of this how can I do that in GDB ?  Below output

```
header = {
        demo1=34324
        demo2=3242342
      }
```

Comment: So, "how can I get GDB to print the contents of only a specific member of a struct"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
p (*(struct demo.head *) 0x7fff1631a0).header
```

Comment: @PavanManjunath: He knows. No need to ask for accepts. It's up to the OP to decide to accept answers.